# Redirect stdout+stderr on a C# Windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, stdout, stderr

I've written a Windows service in C# using the `ServiceBase` helper. During its execution, some procedures in an external native DLL are called. Annoyingly, those procedures write to stdout and/or stderr in an uncontrolled manner as no sources are given for this DLL.

Is it possible to redirect those outputs from the C# service to a log file?

Comment: is it starting up the DLL as a Process? or simply referencing the DLL?

Comment: You can't start a DLL as a process.  This is a common issue.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do this via PInvoke to [SetStdHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setstdhandle):

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true) ]
public static extern int SetStdHandle(int device, IntPtr handle); 

// in your service, dispose on shutdown..
FileStream filestream;
StreamWriter streamwriter;

void Redirect()
{   
    int status;
    IntPtr handle;
    filestream = new FileStream("logfile.txt", FileMode.Create);
    streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
    streamwriter.AutoFlush = true;
    Console.SetOut(streamwriter);
    Console.SetError(streamwriter);

    handle = filestream.Handle;
    status = SetStdHandle(-11, handle); // set stdout
    // Check status as needed
    status = SetStdHandle(-12, handle); // set stderr
    // Check status as needed
}
```

Comment: I've changed the line
   handle = filestream.Handler;
by
   handle = filestream.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
because filestream.Handler is deprecated.

Comment: Any way to use this without a FileStream? (i.e. MemoryStream or similar)?

Comment: @ReedCopsey - Please see my reply to a similar comment on my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555002/redirecting-native-dlls-stdout-to-memory-stream

Comment: @Herchu you did realise the "Dangerous" in DangerousGetHandle? It is there for a reason: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.dangerousgethandle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @RuiMarques Yeah, they call me Danger for a reason! :) Seriously now; that was 2009. If I happen to need it again I'll write it following Steve's solution.

Comment: Regretfully, it does not work on Windows 10.  The file is empty.  I made sure that I Close() on both streamwriter and filestream when done.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Console.SetOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setout#System_Console_SetOut_System_IO_TextWriter_) method.

It will allow you to redirect console output to a TextWriter.

Comment: Depending on how the DLL is written, that won't redirect the DLLs output to the console, though.  Typically, it works, but not always.

Comment: Reed, so what does it depend on?

Comment: To my recent experience, captures only the output that the C# code writes to the Console.