# How do I capture the output of a user defined service into a logfile, without programming?

Tags: logging, windows-services

I'm creating a service using the sc.exe command in windows xp

I want to save the STDOUT messages to svc.datetime.log

How do I do this?

I'm using a batch file as a wrapper to an executable. No heavy lifting or .NET

Comment: This might be a duplicate question.  Look at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579074/redirect-stdoutstderr-on-c-windows-service

Comment: I disagree, see my question update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a logging framework like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) or [EntLib Logging Application Block](http://www.codeplex.com/entlib) to do this (assuming you're using .NET).  There are a lot of pitfalls that you can run into if you're writing you're own, and existing frameworks do a good job.

Comment: No I'm just using a batch file as a wrapper to an executable, no fancy .NET