# Redirect stdout+stderr on a C# GUI project

Tags: .net, c++, dll

I have a unmanaged dll (C++) which I can't change.
How can I get result of STDOUT from this dll to my C# GUI project  ?
for example DLL have void like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void PrintMsg();

void PrintMsg()
{
cout << "Some text" << endl ;
}
```

I find this solution [Redirect stdout+stderr on a C# Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579074/redirect-stdoutstderr-on-a-c-windows-service) , but all redirected data write to file, I need recive stdout without save to output file, the best option get output in a variable.

If possible, tell me how.

Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++ and VB.NET?

Comment: Sorry, I forgte this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510285/c-net-gui-application-native-library-console-stdout-redirection-via-anonymo 
very good way ideal for me, but work only one time, and not answered why :(

Comment: Seth, I have a unmanaged dll for streaming stock prices and main programm written in .net

Comment: OK, but remove the tags that are unnecessary, like VB.NET and C++, because it doesn't really matter what languages your unmanaged dll were written in, or VB.NET just because it's .NET.

Comment: also, your question is unclear. void methods do not have results, so did you just want to redirect stdout for your program?

Comment: Seth, thanks for the comments, I changed the question to a more correct and  remove some tags.
Yes you right, I need to redirect STDOUT from dll to my .NET program.

Comment: yeah, apparently you need a native handle to use `SetStdHandle`. Is using a file and just reading it after output is written an option?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to call [CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and pass it a name unique to your applicaton (NOT A FILENAME) to create a "device".  You'll have to do it twice actually, one for "writing" and one for "reading", and then use [SetStdHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686244%28VS.85%29.aspx) and redirect stdout to the "writing" handle.  You should then be able to use the "reading" handle to read in everything sent to stdout.  I've never tried this, so you'll have to look up exactly how to make an arbitrary communications "device".