# Is it permitted to pass NULL as the handle to SetStdHandle to disable stdout?

Tags: c#, stdout

I have a problem similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579074/redirect-stdoutstderr-on-a-c-sharp-windows-service) where I have a P/Invoked third party DLL that writes to stdout and I'd like to prevent that. In my case instead of redirecting it to a log file I'd like to ignore it.

Is it correct to use `SetStdHandle(StdOuputHandle, IntPtr.Zero)` to do this?

In my testing this seems to work but I haven't been able to find any documentation that states that passing NULL is permitted and will have the desired effect.

The [GetStdHandle documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231(v=vs.85).aspx) states:

> If an application does not have associated standard handles, such as a service running on an interactive desktop, and has not redirected them, the return value is NULL.

but this is far from explicit documentation that NULL means disassociate the existing standard handle in SetStdHandle.